# Standard Meta Language: are hd and tl evaluated right or left first?

Tags: function, functional-programming, metalanguage

In Standard Meta Language, if I have a function that includes multiple successive calls to the `hd` and `tl` functions, will they be executed right to left, or left to right?

Example:

```
- fun secondChar s = tl hd s;
val secondChar = fn : string -> char
```

Will this function return the equivalent of `tl ( hd s)` or `hd (tl s)`?

Comment: You have found a very peculiar ML variant if that's not an error.

Comment: @molbdnilo How so? Are parenthesis required for calling multiple functions at once?

Comment: In Standard ML, if you want to pass the result of `f x` to `g`, you write `g (f x)`. `tl hd s` is the same as `(tl hd) s`. `tl` has type `'a list -> 'a list`. `hd`'s type is `'a list -> 'a`. No `string`s involved. Don't you have an interpreter so you can experiment, or a book that you can study?